# Is android:windowExitAnimation not working?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

As mentioned by Google in this https://youtu.be/N_x7SV3I3P0

view.animation is still the way for Windows transition Animation.

Hence I use

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimations</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_activity</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit_activity</item>
    </style>
```

I only get the enter transition when I get from Activity1 (Hello World) to Activitity2 (Purple). Similar when getting back from Activity2 to Activitiy1, only the enter transition shown. The exit transition can never be triggered.

Shown below is the result.

[image]

Looks like `android:windowExitAnimation` is not working? (i.e. if I remove it, the effect is the same).

To workaround, in my Activity2, I use `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_activity, R.anim.exit_activity)` instead like below.

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_activity, R.anim.exit_activity)
    }

    override fun finish() {
        super.finish()
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_activity, R.anim.exit_activity)
    }
}
```

Then I get the result as I wanted.

[image]

Is there a bug in `android:windowExitAnimation`? Or I miss something?

---

p/s: my transition animation XML as below

enter_activity.xml

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

exit_activity.xml

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I need to use the below instead

```
<style name="WindowAnimations">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_activity</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/exit_activity</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_activity</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/exit_activity</item>
</style>
```

The below is supposed to use for opening up the App or close the App (or background the App), and not for opening different Android Activities (although it is strange that `android:windowEnterAnimation` works for opening activity, and will interfere (mixed) with the `android:activityOpenEnterAnimation` and `android:activityCloseEnterAnimation`)

```
<style name="WindowAnimations">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/enter_activity</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/exit_activity</item>
</style>
```

The `windowEnterAnimation` works but not `windowExitAnimation` though.

Comment: I want to use custom animations when navigating from my Activity to the Activity of **other app** and then when **navigating back to the Activity of my app**. neither of the styles above have been helpful so far. any idea?!

Comment: @Soheil override it programmatically in `onCreate()` after `super.onCreate()` of the `Activity`: `overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);`